# NSDictionary writetofile is not working

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsdictionary

I'm trying to save some user settings using NSDictionary writetofile but it is not working.

I have already checked out similar questions but I could not find out what the problem is.

here's my code:

```
NSDictionary *settings;
NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentationDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *settingsPath = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/UserSettings.plist", [paths objectAtIndex:0]];
BOOL settingsExist = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:settingsPath];
if(settingsExist){
    NSLog(@"file found!");
    settings = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithContentsOfFile:settingsPath];
}else{
    NSLog(@"file not found!");
    settings = [[NSDictionary alloc] initWithObjectsAndKeys:@"iPhone",@"device", nil];
    [[NSFileManager defaultManager] createFileAtPath:settingsPath contents:nil attributes:nil];
    if([settings writeToFile:settingsPath atomically:YES]){
        NSLog(@"success!");
    }else{
        NSLog(@"fail!");
    }
}
```

It keeps returning 'fail!'.
Could you help me with this please?

Comment: I'm sure you meant `NSDocumentDirectory` instead of `NSDocumentationDirectory`. Also, you ***must not*** use format strings for constructing file paths. Use `stringByAppendingPathComponent:` for that purpose.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to specify `NSDocumentDirectory` rather than `NSDocumentationDirectory`.

Comment: Thanks! I was making such a rookie mistake :D

Comment: XCode autocomplete offers the 'incorrect' one first. From what I can see, it might also be used far less, i.e., the list of references to 'NSDocumentationDirectory' on stackoverflow are overwhelming to this same problem: http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=nsdocumentationdirectory  

  
  
  
Small but painful bug.

Comment: @marccenedella Yep, I've been burned by that one myself; it's very easy to miss.